# How to compare multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, min, string-agg

I have a table with data like following, want to return those group_id with unique data. Both group_id 3 and 4 have two component 123 and 456, so they are "duplicated", we just need to return the smaller group_id, that's 3. Also group_id 5 doesn't have a duplication, it can be returned. So we want group_id 3 and 5 to be returned.

How can I write a SQL query against postgres database to achieve that? Thank you!

| id | group_id | component_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 2 | 3 | 456 |
| 3 | 4 | 123 |
| 4 | 4 | 456 |
| 5 | 5 | 123 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(group_id) group_id
FROM (
  SELECT group_id, STRING_AGG(component_id::text, ',' ORDER BY component_id) components
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY group_id
) t
GROUP BY components;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5b1b9d8ab2ba8ba922498d3c24bcd2a1).

Comment: Thank you so much! Good to know STRING_AGG, that's exact solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id, MIN(component_id)
FROM   MyTable
GROUP  BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There are 3 groups in above table, 
group_id 3 with component 123, 456, 
group_id 4 with component 123, 456, 
group_id 5 with component 123
we treat group_id 3 and 4 are duplicated because they all have the same components. 
We need to return 3 and 5. I think your query returns 3, 123; 4, 123.

Comment: Just remove the "MIN(component_id)" from the SELECT clause of the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to assign the group_id's to the component_id's.

It uses a recursive CTE with arrays to find the possible combinations.
The recursion starts from the lonely group_id's.

Then the next CTE picks one of the longest combinations.

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE RCTE AS (
>     SELECT id, group_id, component_id
>     , 1 as Lvl
>     , array[group_id] as group_ids
>     , array[component_id] as component_ids
>     FROM YourTable
>     WHERE group_id IN (
>       SELECT group_id
>       FROM YourTable
>       GROUP BY group_id
>       HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
>     )
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT t.id, t.group_id, t.component_id
>     , Lvl+1
>     , cte.group_ids || t.group_id
>     , cte.component_ids || t.component_id
>     FROM RCTE cte
>     JOIN YourTable t 
>       ON t.group_id != ALL(group_ids)
>      AND t.component_id != ALL(component_ids)
> )
> , CTE_ARRAYS AS (
>     SELECT group_ids, component_ids
>     FROM RCTE
>     ORDER BY array_length(group_ids, 1) desc, Lvl desc
>     LIMIT 1
> ) 
> SELECT a.group_id, a.component_id
> FROM CTE_ARRAYS c
> CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(c.group_ids, c.component_ids) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(group_id, component_id)
> ORDER BY a.group_id;
> ```

| group_id | component_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 456 |
| 5 | 123 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9830c5b21f9c693361b8c2431608b755)*

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a good solution.

Comment: If change the last row to , (5,  5,  789) and add one more row  (6,  3,  789) and change , then expected result is group id 3, 4, 5. But the result is 4, 4, 5.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7ca25a675618760a1f3c39587a10e133

Comment: @zhaoxiongwei  The solution has been completely changed. It's recursive now.